# Selenium (webdriver) or PhantomJS as a proxy

Tags: selenium, proxy, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

We have a small web scraper that serves pretty well for our tasks. However some time ago we faced an issue scraping some hard ajax website. **Is there any way to turn Selenium (or naked PhantomJS) into a HTTP or socks proxy?** So that solution would be running on some port, and we simply set proxy settings in our scraper, pointing them to that solution. I know we can *emulate* the browser actions, but it would require too much time to rewrite the scraper.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't get what you expect to happen if you run your scraper with a phantomjs set up as "proxy". Does the site you want to read require any user interaction before doing the ajax calls? If so, I guess you are out of luck. Please be more specific about the problem.

Comment: @luksch, the website does not require any interactions, it just requires executing complex JS code (dynamic DOM building and ajax). So I need to parse it and return modified "final" HTML (as it would be seen by a normal user).

Comment: I see. Well, this is an interesting idea but I guess you have to write the wrapper around webdriver to act as proxy yourself. It should not be hard though.